# Minimum number of words in the vocabulary for Word2Vec models?

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I have a corpus of short text(~5000 sentences) which forms a vocabulary of ~2000 words. I used Gensim to build a Word2Vec model, but the output from most_similar doesn't look reasonable. Is this because I don't have enough words in the vocabulary? If so, is there any rule of thumbs for the vocabulary size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally word2vec needs a lot of data, with many varied examples of each word, for good word-vectors. You can sometimes squeeze some usefulness out of smaller datasets with:

- smaller vector-dimensionality; and/or
- more training epochs

(While I've not formally tested this, my hunch/rule-of-thumb is vector-dimensionality should be no more than the square-root of the count of unique words. So with only 2000 unique words, even a dimensionality of 50 is pushing it.)

You may be tempted to use a lower-than-default `min_count` so those words that only appear one or two times train vectors. But such vectors without varied usage examples will themselves be poor - dominated by those one or two not-broadly-representative contexts. Also, in aggregate all such "noise" words, interspersed with the words that **do** have enough examples, tend to make those other word-vectors worse. (Discarding words with too few examples usually *improves* the surviving words' vectors.)

If at all possible, get more training data, from a similar usage domain, to mix in with your data of primary interest.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule of thumb for the vocabulary size but each word should appear sufficiently often with other words for the algorithm to compute a meaningful embedding (the default `min_count` in gensim's word2vec is `5`).

There are in fact two underlying algorithms in word2wec: `skip-gram` (`sg=1`) and `CBOW` (`sg=0`). You could try both of them as one may yield better results than the other. You could also experiment with different values for the `window` parameter, which is the maximum distance between the current and predicted word within a sentence.

Finally, if you have a small vocabulary/dataset, you should use a small vector dimension (e.g. `vector_size=50`).